# AWEBER javascript integration

Tags: javascript, forms, aweber

i have 2 raw aweber html code, they are in separate accounts. now i want to have 1 sign up form for this two raw codes. Means when someone sign up on my form, the email should the be saved on my two list. but i got problem on how to integrate this two codes. When i remove 1 form it work for only 1 list but when i integrate the two it doesn't save any email on the two list.

heres my code ,sorry for my poor coding im new to javascript im trying hard to solved this problem hope someone can help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<!--1st-->
<script language="javascript">
function copy_fields(){
    <!--document.getElementById('name1').value = document.getElementById('name').value;
    document.getElementById('from1').value = document.getElementById('email').value;
}
function validate(){
    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/; 
    if((document.submail.email.value=='')||(document.submail.email.value=='Email Address'))
    {alert('Please Enter Email Address'); return false;}
    if (!filter.test(document.submail.email.value)) 
    {alert('Please Enter A Valid Email'); return false;}    

    document.getElementById('sub9').className='gray_out';
    document.getElementById('sub9').disabled='true';    

    copy_fields();
    document.form2.submit();
    setTimeout('document.submail.submit()',3000);   
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.gray_out {
    filter:alpha(opacity=40);
    -moz-opacity:.40;
    opacity:.40;
}
</style>
<!--END 1st-->

<!--2nd-->
<script language="javascript">
function copy_fields1(){
    <!--document.getElementById('name1').value = document.getElementById('name').value;
    document.getElementById('from1').value = document.getElementById('email').value;
}
function validate1(){
    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/; 
    if((document.submail.email.value=='')||(document.submail.email.value=='Email Address'))
    {alert('Please Enter Email Address'); return false;}
    if (!filter.test(document.submail.email.value)) 
    {alert('Please Enter A Valid Email'); return false;}    

    document.getElementById('sub9').className='gray_out';
    document.getElementById('sub9').disabled='true';    

    copy_fields1();
    document.form1.submit();
    setTimeout('document.submail.submit()',3000);   

}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.gray_out {
    filter:alpha(opacity=40);
    -moz-opacity:.40;
    opacity:.40;
}
</style>
<!--END 2nd-->

</head>
<body>

<form name="submail" method="post" action="http://empowerauthoritypro.com/commission-loophole-ninja" >
<input type="hidden" name="go" value="now" />
    <!--    First Name:<br />
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name" value="First Name" onclick="if(this.value=='First Name') this.value=''" class="text-field" /><br />-->
        Email:<br />
        <input id="email" type="text" name="email" value="Email Address" onclick="if(this.value=='Email Address') this.value=''" class="text-field" />
        <!--<a href="#" onclick="return validate();" id="sub9">Optin Now</a>-->
        <input type="button" id="sub9" value="Submit" onClick='window.open(validate1())' />
</form>



<!--1st has email requirement only-->
<form name="form2" method="post" action="http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl" target="iframe" style="display:none">
<input type="hidden" name="meta_web_form_id" value="1817364894" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_split_id" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="listname" value="dummylistshaq" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.aweber.com/thankyou.htm?m=default" /><input type="hidden" name="meta_adtracking" value="ninjatest" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_message" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_required" value="email" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_tooltip" value="" />
<div style="display:none">
<img src="http://forms.aweber.com/form/displays.htm?id=jByM7MxsLBycLA==" alt="" width="1" height="1" />
</div>
<input type="text" name="email" id="from1" value="" size="20">
</form>
<iframe name="iframe" style="display:none"></iframe>
<!--END 1st-->

<!--2nd has name and email requirement but i have compromise the name to be hide-->
<form name="form1" method="post" action="http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl" target="iframe" style="display:none">
<input type="hidden" name="meta_web_form_id" value="1376972149" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_split_id" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="listname" value="optinninja1" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.aweber.com/thankyou.htm?m=default" /><input type="hidden" name="meta_adtracking" value="ninjaoptin" /><input type="hidden" name="meta_message" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_required" value="name,email" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_tooltip" value="" />
<div style="display:none">
<img src="http://forms.aweber.com/form/displays.htm?id=jMzsbJzsTIwsnA==" alt="" width="1" height="1" />
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="name" id="name1" value="" size="20">
<input type="text" name="email" id="from1" value="" size="20">
</form>
<iframe name="iframe" style="display:none"></iframe>
<!--END 2nd-->


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

A better (and AWeber-supported) way to integrate multiple services with your AWeber list is to use the AWeber API.

Another possibility might be to set up a PHP page on your own site, set it as your AWeber Form's "Thank You Page", and code your PHP to take advantage of the Pass Subscriber Data feature:

https://help.aweber.com/entries/21775518-how-do-i-pass-form-data-to-my-thank-you-pages

I'm a bit confused regarding your desired workflow. You mention submitting to two AWeber lists, yet there is a third form in your code as well that posts to a third party.

I highly recommend getting in touch with AWeber Customer Solutions who will be able to address your needs more comprehensively.  Just email help@aweber.com or visit https://www.aweber.com/contact-us.htm and a team member will take an in-depth look.

Comment: the two forms before the </body> tag was the aweber raw code but thats hidden. the main form is the form in the middle asking for email address then email use to be stored in a variable , then be used by the two hidden forms and submit it. but it doesnt seem to work.